# What is the "Bitcoin stick"?

Tags: hardware-wallet, academic-research

I've encountered the page on ["Bitcoin stick"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_stick) while browsing the [Research wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Research). The information provided on the subject is quite small. Can anyone explain what it really is and where one can find more information on the subject?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IavQ-Wc8S1U

> Clemens Cap of Uni Rostock explains the Electronic Bitcoin wallet
> device he's working on. It's based on adafruit microtouch device.
>
> This
> is a small takeout of Clemens' talk at the Bitcoin Conference in
> Prague 2011